# How to run a collection with specific environment triggered from postman web-hook

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-newman

I am trying to trigger the postman collection to run when code is deployed successfully through postman web-hook.

So, I created a web-hook as per their documentation [Postman API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/12959542/UV5XjJV8#8bec7537-cc5d-4ed7-a995-c7753e55ed28), to run my collection, whenever the latest code is getting deployed on the server. The collection needs to run under specific postman environment. So when, I hit the the web-hook it has started running the collection with no environment, I did a lot of google though but haven't found any way to trigger the collection with specific environment. And the result are also getting added in different workspace even though i have added the workspace id.

Payload:

```
{
    "webhook":{
        "name": "Test Webhook",
        "collection": "{{collection id}}",
        "workspace" : "{{workspace id}}"
    }
}
```

I am stuck in this from last few days, so need to find a way as soon as possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.